# Getting error while using useState with textarea

Tags: reactjs, textarea, use-state, react-functional-component

---

I am getting this warning.
Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
I am using a functional component . I initialised description using useState.

```
 const [description, SetDescription] = useState('');
```

Then I call an API from where I get an array data. data.description is not empty and gives right result I  have checked it by console.log.

```
 SetDescription(data.description);
```

This is the code for textarea.

```
<textarea
      id="description"
      value={description}
      onChange={(e) => {
          SetDescription(e.target.value);
      }}
  />
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're setting the initial state:

`const [description, SetDescription] = useState('');`

Try this:

```
const [description, SetDescription] = useState();

<textarea
      id="description"
      value={description || ''}
      onChange={(e) => {
          SetDescription(e.target.value);
      }}
  />
```

Added a sandbox example of this working https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-fire-5gf1g?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [description, SetDescription] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => SetDescription(json.title));
  }, []);

  return (
    <textarea
      id="description"
      value={description || ""}
      onChange={(e) => {
        SetDescription(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Also you haven't stated how you are fetching data from api, this is important as it needs to be in a `useEffect` or using a `useCallback`. I've updated the sandbox link to show this so when you type into the textarea, it will update the state correctly for the textarea.

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong @KanishkaVijayvargiya because it's working on my sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-fire-5gf1g?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then to receive data from the server you need to use the useEffect hook.

```
export default function App() {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setDescription(JSON.stringify(json)));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea
        value={description || ""}
        onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

What is the format of the data received from the server?

Comment: I am using the useEffect hook only. There is no problem in the API part.

Answer (score -2):

as your error message says **This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen**.
You can try checking for the response and only assign value if data.description is not undefined.

```js
if (data && data.description) SetDescription(data.description);
```

this may solve your warning